# Geoserver ImageMosaic: error connecting to WorldImage

Tags: geoserver, raster, boundless-suite, image-mosaic

I would like to use the ImageMosaic plugin to set up a Geoserver layer which refers to a WorldImage, just like in the [official tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html).

As a simple test case, I put a custom folder into my Geoserver data directory with one World Image (image + WorldFile + projection). When I specify the folder location to a ImageMosaic Store in Geoserver, it simply displays the error message:

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Argument "value" should not be null.
```

On the other hand, when I put my image into a default folder that comes with the openGeo suite (like `file:data/dem/` with the Medform Digital Elevation Data), the thing works as it should.

So I suspect there is something going wrong with user rights, can anybody enlighten me?

---

PS: My Geoserver error log

```
    INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:mosaic
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Argument "value" should not be null.
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:123)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "value" should not be null.
    at org.geotools.util.SoftValueHashMap.ensureNotNull(SoftValueHashMap.java:140)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution: contrary to other data sources for Geoserver, it seems that when you deal with an ImageMosaic you strictly need your data folder to be owned by user/usergroup `tomcat6`. So changing the user/usergroup from `root` to `tomcat6` resolved the problem for me.

Useful commands for Linux:

- display file ownership: `$ ls -l` (2nd column: owner, 3rd column: owner group)
- change file owner: `$ chown myownername myfile` (add option `-R` for folders)
- change file owner group: `$ chgrp myownername myfile` (add option `-R` for folders)

Comment: Heho! Which OS and Geoserver distribution do you use? I have the same issue and can't fix it. I use Geoserver 2.3.3 binary release on OpenSuse 12.3 and have only the Appache-user wwwrun, no user tomcat6. Did you change ownership of the whole geoserver's data-folder or only of the folder containing your images?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 using GeoServer 2.2 (shipped with the OpenGeo Suite). I only changed the ownership of the folder containing the images. My GeoServer data folder is owned by `tomcat6` by default. Maybe have a look at my original revision of the post including some more details on my failed attempts...

Comment: I played the whole day: The ImageMosaic in Geoserver 2.3.3 binary distribution works in Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.4. Further the WAR-distribution works under Ubuntu 10.4 (Tomcat 6) under 12.4 (Tomcat 7) like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: In case of standard ubuntu installation `sudo chmod -R geoserver:geoserver mydatafolder` worked. And it was not enough that all files/subfolders were under this user, also first level data subfolder had to be chown correctly.