# Failed to create reader using geoserver Image Pyramid plug-in

Tags: geoserver, image-pyramids

I am following instructions on this link,
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagepyramid/imagepyramid.html

I am pointing the URL to the folder normally but I get the following error,
"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///mnt/MapData/bmpyramid and hints null"

The difference is that in my case, I used a mosaic.vrt file to create the image pyramids. If that was the problem, what would the solution be?

Comment: I found the answer here,
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64645/geoserver-imagemosaic-error-connecting-to-worldimage
It had to do with file permissions.